# Python - Access nested enum value

Tags: python

From `Color.RED`, I would like to access `FOO`'s value of `2`. Is that possible?

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED = BOO.FOO
    BLUE = BOO.BAR

class Person(Enum):
    FOO = 2
    BAR = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you wanted to use `Person.FOO` instead of `BOO.FOO`:

```
class Person(Enum):
    FOO = 2
    BAR = 3

class Color(Enum):
    RED = Person.FOO.value
    BLUE = Person.BAR.value
```

Note that just using `Person.FOO` will get the enumeration member and not its value. If you need the value, you will have to declare it as shown above.

If you just define `RED = Person.FOO`, to access the value you will have to use `Color.RED.value.value`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the class declaration else code raised an exception: `NameError: name 'Person' is not defined`

```
class Person(Enum):
    FOO = 2
    BAR = 3

class Color(Enum):
    RED = Person.FOO.value
    BLUE = Person.BAR.value
```

Answer (score 0):

BOO and Person don't match, but assuming you're wanting them to: you can access the raw value of an enum using `.value` and they chain together just fine.

```py
from enum import Enum

class Boo(Enum):
    FOO = 2
    BAR = 3

class Color(Enum):
    RED = Boo.FOO
    BLUE = Boo.BAR

print(Color.RED.value.value) # prints 2
```